# Way to find element by style?

Tags: cypress, styles

HTML:

```html
<div class="example-event Gantt-event event_class_color Gannt-event-another-edit"
  data-object-type-id="4" data-is-people="true" data-is-taken="false" 
  data-is-externalorder="false" data-is-inaccessibility="false"
  data-work-status="1" title="SEPP-16288"
  style="width: 400px; height: 18px; left: 400px; top: 5px; line-height: 18px;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(255, 243, 204), 
      rgb(255, 243, 204) 10px, rgb(249, 30, 26) 10px,
      rgb(249, 30, 26) 20px);">
</div>
```

I have couple the same elements but with different styles. Is there any way in Cypress to select element by style but in shorter version than:

```js
cy.get('[style="width: 400px; height: 18px; left: 400px; top: 5px; line-height: 18px; 
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
   45deg, 
   rgb(255, 243, 204), 
   rgb(255, 243, 204) 10px, 
   rgb(249, 30, 26) 10px, 
   rgb(249, 30, 26) 20px
  );"]'
)
```

For example only using background color or height?

Comment: You have a few `data` attributes. If they don't change each run, can you work with those?

Answer (score 6):

I think use `title` as this is what user sees when hovering the event on the Gantt chart.

```js
cy.get('[title="SEPP-16288"]')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `*` with `cy.get('[style=` like this `cy.get('[style*=` to do a contains search.

```
cy.get('[style*="background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(255, 243, 204)"]')
```

With that said, I would try other ways of targeting your element before doing such a selector. Have you tried targeting the parent element and doing a `within( ($el) => {})`. This way you limit what can be found to a limited number of elements usually allowing you to use more verbose selectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use the background colour you can use this:

```js
cy.get('[style*="background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(255, 243, 204)"]')
```

If you want to use height you can do this:

```js
cy.get('[style*="height: 18px"]')
```

Or, a better approach would be to use the `data-is-` attributes. Assuming the attribute `data-object-type-id` will be unique for every element, you can use this. In case, this is not unique you can search for attributes which have unique and constant values.

```js
cy.get('[data-object-type-id="4"]')
```